# Prompt message on closing tab without user interaction?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one HTML page which contains only info, no user input, and redirects after 3 seconds. Is it possible to prompt a confirmation message if the user decides to close the tab?

That method only works if there is some user interaction like clicking on the page or adding text to input:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.returnValue = '';
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: I think most browsers override the `beforeunload` event these days due to pop ups so you can't specify a message - maybe just notify the user on the page content to wait for the redirect

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), you will see a note as follows.

> To combat unwanted pop-ups, some browsers don't display prompts created in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted with. Moreover, some don't display them at all.

So no. The `onbeforeunload` property should not really be used as you can not rely on the browser honouring it.